# How to delete property from object mongoDb mongoose nodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to delete the _id property in my function so that mongoDb create a new one for me when I try to copy a document. I have tried the following but the _id remains without being deleted

```
TemplateInfo.find(req.query).exec(function (err, doc) {
      //console.log(doc);
      var newdoc = new Templates(doc[0]);
      delete newdoc_id; //= mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
      //newdoc.save();
      console.log("new doc", newdoc);
    });
```

results still have _id property

main goal is that I am trying to copy a document that is in the templateinfo collection to the template collection.

Comment: Try to lean your query, with [`.lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `select` function to exclude to `_id` property :

```
TemplateInfo.find(req.query).select('-_id').exec(function (err, doc) {
  //console.log(doc);
  var newdoc = new Templates(doc[0]);
  delete newdoc_id; //= mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
  //newdoc.save();
  console.log("new doc", newdoc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete _id index from mongodb document you can only hide it using `select("-id")` or you can rename it while printing.

1)Hiding _id

```
TemplateInfo.find(req.query).select("-_id").exec(function (err, doc) {
  //console.log(doc);
  var newdoc = new Templates(doc[0]);
  delete newdoc_id; //= mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
  //newdoc.save();
  console.log("new doc", newdoc);
});
```

2)Renaming _id Property (Add below code in mongodb model )

```
EmployeeSchema.set("toJSON", {
  transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
    ret.EmpRefNo = ret._id;
    delete ret._id;
  },
});
```